# How to horizontally center text of zero-width element?

Tags: css, border, text-align

As you can see in the snippet below, the left border represents the center of the element.  The text begins to the right of the border.

However, I need the text to be centered on the border, while remaining zero-width.

So I need to shift the text to the left somehow, but `text-align: center` and `text-align: middle` have no effect.

I can't translate the entire element because then the border would be translated to the wrong place.

The purpose of this element is to be a tick mark for the horizontal axis of a chart.

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
```

Comment: How about using `::before` or `::after` pseudo element?

Comment: Also try `text-indent: -10px;`

Comment: It's interesting that you have to have it zero width. Would position absolute not work (so you could have the line as a linear-gradient background). Pseudo element gives you the right visual solution but screen reader users may never hear these axis markers. This may or may not matter to their understanding of your particular application of course, I can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flexbox is the easiest way here:

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Sato Takeru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16431842/sato-takeru)'s comment I've decided to use a pseudo element.

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

div::before {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  content: 'foo';
  width: 4em;
  transform: translateX(-2em);
}
```

```html
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
}

span:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<span>foo</span>
```